# Missing a temporary folder in wp app

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress application installed . Now if i tried to upload media file it show me the error **missing a temporary folder** . I also define a path for temp directory . I also edit the php.ini file **upload_tmp_dir** variable. My php.ini file content is

```
upload_tmp_dir = "c:\window\temp"
```

Nothing helped me . any help will be appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Create 2 folders in your WordPress root, `/tmp` `/wwwtmp`

2) set permissions for above folders to 777

It should solve your issue.

If it will not solve your problem, follow steps given in below link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165184/missing-a-temporary-folder-despite-settings-in-wp-config-php